# Accessing XMLBeans generated schemas.jar in Maven project

Tags: java, maven-2, xmlbeans

I have a `schemas.jar` supplied to me and am trying to access it from within a simple Maven project.  I have put the `schemas.jar` file in my `src/main/resources` directory, which is in my classpath.

When I am trying to access the created documents with something like:

```
GetOrdersRequestDocument getOrdersRequestDocument = GetOrdersRequestDocument.Factory.newInstance();
```

It complains about the `GetOrdersRequestDocument` (can't find it).

How do I get the project to pick up these classes?  Do I need to import anything specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have put the schemas.jar file in my src/main/resources directory, which is in my classpath.

Yes, the files in `src/main/resources` directory are on your classpath. But this doesn't mean that the content of the jar itself is directly available. You could use a [`URLClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load the JAR though.

But... this is not how I would do things. If this is an option, I would just install the JAR in your corporate or local repository (using [`install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html)) and declare it as a dependency. This would make  the content of your JAR available to your code, like any other dependency.

Comment: Once I did this I could then import the relevant classes and it worked.  Thanks